# Macro overwrites existing data

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the following code it pass values to specified cells in Sheet2, but it also overwrites the existing data and cleans whatever was there.

```
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim a As Variant, o As Variant
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim a As Variant, o As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
a = w1.Range("A1:H" & w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

ReDim o(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 8)
For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
If a(i, 2) <> "Red apple" Then
   j = j + 1
   o(j, 4) = a(i, 3)
   o(j, 6) = a(i, 5)
   o(j, 8) = a(i, 7)


  ElseIf a(i, 2) = "Red apple" And a(i + 1, 2) = "Green apple" Then
    j = j + 1
        o(j, 4) = a(i, 3) + a(i + 1, 3)
        o(j, 6) = a(i, 5) + a(i + 1, 5)
        o(j, 8) = a(i, 7) + a(i + 1, 7)
    i = i + 1
  Else
    j = j + 1
    o(j, 4) = a(i, 3)
    o(j, 6) = a(i, 5)
    o(j, 8) = a(i, 7)
  End If
Next i
With w2
  .Columns(1).ClearContents
  .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(o, 1), UBound(o, 2)) = o
  .Columns(1).AutoFit
  .Activate
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

sheet1:

```
    A   B           C   D   E   F   G   H
sheet1  orange      89      89      89  
sheet2  Banana      56      56      56  
sheet3  Red apple   154     78      78  
sheet4  Green apple 76      76      76  
sheet5  orange      44      44      44  
sheet6  Banana      33      33      33  
sheet7  Red apple   22      22      32  
sheet8  Green apple 78      78      78  
sheet9  orange      90      56      33  
sheet10 Banana      22      22      22  
sheet11 Red apple   57      35      35  
sheet12 Green apple 90      22      22
```

Sheet2:

```
yyy yy  yy  88      88      88
yyy yy  yy  88      88      88
yyy yy  yy  134     134     134
yyy yy  yy  34      55      55
yyy yy  yy  33      55      55
yyy yy  yy  123     123     123
yyy yy  yy  55      55      55
yyy yy  yy  5       3       8
yyy yy  yy  110     110     110
yyy yy  yy  34      90      22
yyy yy  yy  12      76      11
yyy yy  yy  55      55      55
yyy yy  yy  55      55      55
```

Comment: And what you want ? ;).

Answer (score 0):

Several points that needed fixes:
1. Explicitly altering the value of a loop variable is a BAD THING. If you feel the need to do so (like in your present code), rethink the logic. Here, the logic is that you copy the values from `a` to `o` no matter what; and only if the row title says 'Green apples' you *add* the values instead of copying. The conditional now reflects this.
2. Your output holds only 3 significant columns (4,6,8) yet the array is just as big as the source array. No wonder the unused elements overwrite the target sheet range with ... nothing as they are empty. I've moved the upper left corner to `D1` and shortened the target range to what the output array holds. Output columns now start at 4.
3. It's unclear why you clear and format column 1 in the target sheet, as you never write to it.
4. Just as an aside: use `Option Explicit` and explicit variable declarations, and do assign something to a variable before it's first use (here: `j`).

```
  Option Explicit
  Sub copystuff()
     Dim i As Long, j As Long
     Dim a, o

     ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
     Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
     ' copy source values into field a
     a = w1.Range("A1:H" & w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

     ReDim o(1 To UBound(a, 1), 4 To 8)
     j = 1
     For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        If a(i, 2) = "Green apple" Then
           j = j - 1
           o(j, 4) = o(j, 4) + a(i, 3)
           o(j, 6) = o(j, 6) + a(i, 5)
           o(j, 8) = o(j, 8) + a(i, 7)
        Else
           o(j, 4) = a(i, 3)
           o(j, 6) = a(i, 5)
           o(j, 8) = a(i, 7)
        End If
        j = j + 1
     Next i

     With w2
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Range("D1").Resize(UBound(o, 1), UBound(o, 2) - LBound(o, 2) + 1) = o
        .Columns(1).AutoFit
        .Activate
     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @user1016274 thank your for help. I have run the program as it is, but I did see any reaction. the look is not working. any advise would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I guest I need to give better explanation. Next i in not working at all. I can even tell whether it was reading.

Comment: I've created a new worksheet with 2 sheets, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". I copied the data you posted to Sheet1 and ran the sub. Data was copied and added to Sheet2, as intended. What do you see when you run the code? Any error messages? You can single-step through the sub in the VBA editor and see what it does in every step.

Comment: my apology to user1016274. Your code was perfect and it was me who did wrong when I was doing some changes.  The code was not only working, taking you time to give the explanation and with detail is appreciated.

Comment: Never mind, I'm glad it works for you now. If you are satisfied with my answer then please "accept" it by clicking the icon left of it.